# rsync params to create, delete but not UPDATE files

Tags: backup, rsync

Currently I'm using rysnc to create a remote backup of certain folders and subfolders and I would like to achieve a very particular behaviour. I want to add the new files, remove the ones that no longer exists **but never update an existing file**.

It's something related to security, we add new files to those folders and remove some from time to time but NEVER change the contents of existing files. We would like to keep it as it was created.

This is my current rsync command (part of a bash script)

```
rsync -a --delete /srv/backup/ xxx@xxxx:~/backups/
```

I've seen the --ignore-existing option but this disables the --delete option

Answer (score 0):

Ups, nevermind. Rsync it's a fantastic tool!

You can combine both --ignore-existing and --delete to achieve exactly what I'm asking for: add new files, delete no longer existing but do not update.

```
$mkdir folder1 folder2
$touch folder1/sample1 folder1/sample2
$rsync -a --ignore-existing --delete folder1/ folder2/
$ls folder2/
sample1  sample2
$echo "this is an update" > folder1/sample2
$cat folder1/sample2 
this is an update
$rm folder1/sample1
$touch folder1/sample3
$rsync -a --ignore-existing --delete folder1/ folder2/
$ls folder2
sample2  sample3 -- (sample1 deleted)
$cat folder2/sample2 
(empty sample2 has not been updated)
```